# Google Analytics Custom Site Search (Lucene / Sql Server Full Text Search)

Tags: google-analytics

we have developed a Custom Search Solution in our Website (Drug Data Website) which uses Lucene indexes.

The User performs "search" by providing "catergory" ("Generic Drugs or Rx drugs) and specify the Drug Name in the "Keyword" and the system calls Lucene to return back the results.

We would like to use Google Analytics to give us Search metrics such as

How frequently do visitors use my search box and what are they looking for?

Are visitors satisfied with what they find?

What are most popular keywords?

How much time it takes to return results based on the Search "Keyword"

Do users actually use Search Results?

So my Question is? 
 Is it possible to use Google Analytic Site Search Feature which I think only works with Google Search Engine ?

if not Google Site Search then what are the possible alternatives/Solutions  in Google Analytics?

Comment: did you got this done with Google Analytics ?

Comment: yes we have to use Track Event and calculate the time by our own.

Answer (score 0):

> How frequently do visitors use my search box and what are they looking for?

You can have this metric using `Google Analytics Site Search Feature`

> Are visitors satisfied with what they find?

Not sure about this but this can be very well derived from the metrics like `bounce-rate`/`exit-rate`

> What are most popular keywords?

[image]

This is also available in `Google Analytics`

> How much time it takes to return results based on the Search "Keyword"

The `page load time` of the search result page would provide you an approximate estimate of this metric

> Do users actually use Search Results?

In google analytics you get the `number of visits which used search`
[image]

Google Analytic Site Search Feature works with **your** website and not with `Google Search Engine`

You might want to read more about this. To start with - an [article from Avinash Kaushik's blog](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/kick-butt-with-internal-site-search-analytics/)

Hope this helps.